# span of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to get familiar with identifying the span of a subspace. I can kind of understand that if M is a subspace of all polynomials of degree <= 2, then the span of M = {1, x, x^2} ....This is because 1, x and x^2 are all polynomials of degree less than 2. And all f in W will be come linear combo of 1, x and x^2.

However, if W is a subspace consisting of all those polynomials (still of degree <= 2) whose second derivative f''(x) = 0 -- what would W's span be? Would its span just be = {1, x} ?

---

It was helpfully confirmed that this span is correct. However, I'm actually trying to find the orthogonal projection of x^2 onto this subspace with respect to the inner product(which is an integral of f(x)g(x) from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f''(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f'(x) = c \Rightarrow f(x) = cx + d
$$

It would be the span of $\{ 1, x \}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the second derivative is 0 for your set $\{1, x, x^2\}$ that means that any coefficient of the $x^2$ term must be $0$.  This limits your space to $\{1, x\}$.